# Allow Users to Edit Ranges" does not work on Sharepoint 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I have an excel spreadsheet (Office 365) that I need different users be able to update different ranges in the sheet. I would like this to work on SharePoint via excel online so the users can collaborate but the protection its not working.  However, the allow user Edit Ranges protection in Excel (desktop) works fine but once I upload it to Sharepoint it doesn't work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does your file have macros? So far any file I saved to SharePoint I had to turn off the Excel 365 AutoSave feature for it to work properly (and I put code in VBA to disable AutoSave for any user that opens it). Please let me know if that applies to you and I will share the VBA code that I used.

Comment: No macros or VBA but I’ll test out turning off the auto save.  But then the users would be required to save it right?   If you valued share the code that would be great.